# What is the source of the term Use Map Settings?

Tags: starcraft-2, terminology

I heard the term "UMS" used to refer to a starcraft II custom map, and after looking it up it seems to refer to "Use Map Settings". What is the origin and history of this term?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The source is the original StarCraft, where the game mode for these custom maps was called "Use Map Settings":

[image]
(image from [here](http://jooh.no/ss_starcraft5.html))

It means the gameplay rules should be derived from the data in the map itself, instead of the regular StarCraft gameplay rules.